# How can I obtain user location information such as state/region and country from the Facebook Graph API without using FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

How can I obtain user location information such as state/region and country from the Facebook Graph API without using FQL? According to Facebook documentation, FQL is deprecated after v2.1 so that will not be a solution for much longer. With the Facebook Graph API, if I use a get request to retrieve '/v2.2/me', I can obtain a location object containing a page ID of 112747725406609 and a location name containing a city and region. If I use a GET request to retrieve the page object from '/v2.2/112747725406609', that page object has a location object with a NULL state and country value; however, it does have a latitude and longitude value.

I know from my website I can turn an IP address into a location using a MaxMind IP Location Database. I know that I could use the latitude and longitude to query the Google Map API to get a more precise location. However, I am looking for a solution that does not require an external database or external API other than the Facebook Graph API.

Anybody have any suggestions or recommendations?

Comment: If the Graph API does not provide that information with the location object (it does for some, but not for others – it just depends on how/with what level of detail that particular object was created), then this is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I realize that the country and region information may not be available for every object but it just makes me wonder why it would be available via FQL and not via the Graph API? Sure I could use FQL until it is deprecated but I would rather deliver code to my client that will actually work for quite some time. I wonder if I am not passing the access token correctly or perhaps need to trade one in for another first. It is not showing for the Graph API Explorer either though. The more I look into this, the more I think another API or external database may be needed.